# Find out if and how a chess game was finished

Tags: python, python-3.x, chess, stockfish

I'm using Stockfish 15 and Python 3.10 to build a browser chessgame.
Now I'm struggling to figure out if a game is over (win, lose, draw).

I have now searched for hours in forums etc. for an answer and found none. Can anyone help me further?

Comment: Python-chess has a `board.is_checkmate()` option: https://python-chess.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Any game that is not a checkmate can be a draw by repetition, I think you need the history of the last moves to check for a draw.

Comment: But that is a client side check. I want a server side check to prevent manipulation from client side.

And I have the history for each game stored in a database.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I mistook it with another js lib.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `python-chess` package has a `board.is_checkmate()` option:

[python-chess.readthedocs.io/en/latest](https://python-chess.readthedocs.io/en/latest)

Any game that is not a checkmate can be a draw by repetition, so having the history of the moves in the game is necessary. Knowing the history of the game, `python-chess` can also look for draws, stalemates, general outcome, etc.

```
import chess
board = chess.Board()

board.is_checkmate()
board.is_stalemate()
board.outcome()
board.can_claim_draw()
board.can_claim_threefold_repetition()
board.can_claim_fifty_moves()
board.is_insufficient_material()
board.is_fivefold_repetition()
board.is_seventyfive_moves()
```